# wrong to calculate the gaussian distribution in python

Tags: python

I am quite new to python, right now I am using python to do a exercise on computing the Gaussian distribution.

Here in the example, mean is 100, standard deviation is 10, then I need to calculate the pdf in 90 and 110.

my code is like

```
def gaussian_distribution(x , mean, dev):
    k = 1.0/ (dev * math.sqrt(2*math.pi))
    s = -1.0/ ( 2* dev*dev )
    return k * math.exp( (x-mean)*(x-mean) * s )

print gaussian_distribution( 110, 100, 10), gaussian_distribution( 90, 100, 10)
```

but the values are both 0.0241970724519, which is wrong, different from the answer 0.84 and 0.1 from o[nline calculator](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/normal.aspx).

I don't know what goes wrong with my function in python

Comment: What about output k and s (which you can also calculate by hand) to see if those are correct? Testing now.

Comment: I would expect those to both give the same answer, as `((110 - 100) ** 2) == ((90 - 100) ** 2) == 100`

Comment: I know they are equal in my equation,  somehow I don't figure out what goes wrong, normally they should be different

Comment: Does your online calculator calculate `pdf` or `cdf`?

Comment: Oh, you are right, I think the online calculator calculates cdf, how can I transform this case to cdf, I think I want to see my result in cdf

Comment: Your online calculator is calculating CDF, but you want PDF, so your Python has calculated the correct value (as proven below by @Zhenya)

Answer (score 2):

Your `pdf` is correct, while your online calculator gives you `cdf`, the cumulative distribution function.

The latter is, by definition, an integral of the pdf from negative infinity to the argument, so:

```
>>> from scipy.integrate import quad
>>> quad(gaussian_distribution, -np.inf, 110, args=(100., 10.))
(0.841344746068544, 1.1360408153147754e-08)
```

Unless it's a self-inflicted learning exercise, just use `scipy.stats`:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import norm
>>> norm.pdf(110, loc=100., scale=10.)
0.024197072451914336
>>> norm.cdf(110, loc=100., scale=10.)
0.84134474606854293
```

Comment: "Unless it's a self-inflicted learning exercise", or a homework assignment.